# WinEdt 10.2 cannot find the file specified

Tags: errors, console

Error launching Console Application PDFLaTeX ...

Command Line: pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "article.tex"

Startup Folder: D:\Article - number3

The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: do you have tex system installed? which one? what does the diagnosis tab from winedt report?

Comment: Welcome to TEX SE! Installing a TeX editor does not mean you installed LaTeX. Your editor is looking for tex binaries that weren't installed if you didn't install a tex system (see Ulrike comment), like texlive, MikTeX or proTEXt.